# How do I stop the pygame window freezing up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

When I run the code a blue rect is displayed in its proper location however the entire window freezes and eventually crashes. How can I fix this?

```
import pygame
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")
run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    filled_rect = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 25, 25)

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,255), filled_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an event loop. Handle the events, by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get). Thus the IO and internal events are handled and the window keeps responding. e.g.:

```
import pygame

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("First Game")

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    # handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # clear the disaply
    win.fill(0)

    # draw the scene
    filled_rect = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 25, 25)
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,255), filled_rect)

    # update the dispaly
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Oddly enough I just copy and pasted your code and the window is still freezing, I can't imagine why I wouldn't work however.

Comment: I copied and pasted @Rabbid76's code and it works fine for me. Window isn't freezing.

Comment: It freezes when you try to close the window.